# print all the month_year values from start to current in python

Tags: python, python-datetime

I've a start year_month value and current year_month value.

```
import datetime

start_yearmonth = 202011
current_yearmonth =  format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m"))
```

How do I print all the yearmonth values between the range?

Result 'd be like

```
>202011,202012,202101,202102,202103
```

Comment: Why not have a seperate variable for months and years and increment them until you have today's time

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with `freq='M'`. And then trasform it to a list

Comment: Arguably the lightest and most flexible solution (not discounting payload to import pandas)  -- except it only returns up to end of the month before the current month - assuming I use current calendar date (i.e. - dm = pd.date_range(start='2020-11' , end='2021-03' , freq='M') - print (dm) - runs up to '2021-02-28' - let me know how we frig pd.datetime show current month please?

Comment: @irnerd, thanks for pointing out the issue with my code. I have updated the code. See the tweak (it was freq=T vs freq=M). You can actually give periods=n to give you n months from start date

Comment: @irnerd, according the documentation, it can be done by passing `closed=None`. Then function must return range with last date (the current one)

Comment: @Roman_N - not looking to be a pain - but - - closed=None is default on that function anyway.  Apologies if I am being too literal - but this does not change the behaviour:  dm = pd.date_range(start='2020-11' , end='2021-03' , freq='M', closed=None)

In [89]: print(dm)
DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-30', '2020-12-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-02-28'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your `start_yearmonth` as `int`, you just need to check for a year change:

```
import datetime

start_yearmonth = 202011
current_yearmonth = int(format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m")))

while start_yearmonth <= current_yearmonth:
    if str(start_yearmonth).endswith("13"):
        start_yearmonth += 100 - 12
    print(start_yearmonth)
    start_yearmonth += 1
```

Out:

```
202011
202012
202101
202102
202103
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will help you

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

start_yearmonth = "202011"
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_yearmonth, "%Y%m")

while datetime.datetime.now() > start_date :
    print(start_date.strftime("%Y%m"))
    start_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=+1)
```

**Output**

```
202011
202012
202101
202102
202103
```

I just use `start_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=+1)` and add month and then just check the `date` with this condition `datetime.datetime.now() > start_date`

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using Pandas, you can do this.

[`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) will convert the value to a datetime format.

[`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) can be used to create the range of dates. [`freq='M'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) will give you month wise increment.

The earlier post had `freq='T'` which is for minutes. `freq='M'` is for months.

```
import pandas as pd
start_yearmonth = 202011
start_yearmonth = pd.to_datetime(start_yearmonth,format='%Y%m')
year_months = pd.date_range(start_yearmonth,periods=5,freq='M').strftime('%Y%m').tolist()
print (year_months)
```

Output will be:

```
['202011', '202012', '202101', '202102', '202103']
```

If you want the results as integers, you can change the `pd.date_range` to return integers.

```
year_months = pd.date_range(start_yearmonth,periods=5,freq='M').strftime('%Y%m').astype(int).tolist()
```

The output of this will be:

```
[202011, 202012, 202101, 202102, 202103]
```

Comment: All values in output list are the same?

Comment: found the issue. It was `freq='T'` which is for minutes. I should have done `freq='M'` for months

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np

start_yearmonth = datetime.strptime('20201101','%Y%m%d')
current_yearmonth =  format(datetime.now()+timedelta(31))
x = np.arange(start_yearmonth, current_yearmonth,  np.timedelta64(1, 'M'),  dtype='datetime64[M]') 
np.core.defchararray.replace(np.datetime_as_string(x,unit='M'),'-','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is there only one variable to hold both years and month. That makes the whole thing a bit more complicated and un-pythonic

```
import datetime

#Start time
year, month = 2020, 11

#gets current time and splits it into a list
current_yearmonth = format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y %m")).split()
print(current_yearmonth)


cur_year = int(current_yearmonth[0])
cur_month = int(current_yearmonth[1])


#increments month until the dates match
while (cur_year != year or cur_month != month):
    print(year, month)
    if month == 13:
        month = 1
        year += 1
    month+=1
```